# Highcharts 5 tooltip colour with custom css class

Tags: highcharts

I'm using Highcharts 5 in styled mode.

https://jsfiddle.net/franzl/va8cz88o/

```
series: [{
    className: "graph-red",
    data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031]
}]
```

The jsfiddle defines a CSS class for colouring a data series red, but this class name doesn't appear to propagate down to the tooltip when hovering over the points.

Is there anyway to specify the class name for the tooltip? I've scanned through the documentation, but I can't find the correct way to handle this.

Comment: @Franzi Do you want the tooltip data to be shown red?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @Franzi Is this what you need ? https://jsfiddle.net/sarojsasmal/va8cz88o/1/

Comment: It's approximating what I'm after, but it hasn't changed the border of the tooltip, which still retains the highcharts-color-0 colouring, which is the class name appended to the series by default.

Comment: @Franzi You can set the border color as well. How do you want to customize the border?

Comment: Hi, the border colour is ignored by the styled version of Highcharts though, I believe, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: @Franzi did you find any solutions ti this ?  i removed the highchart.css (this is probably you don't want to do i guess) also included highstock.js instead of highchart.js . Here is the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sarojsasmal/va8cz88o/3/

Comment: Based on my original fiddle, I find that the borderColor only works if I use this script:

    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

rather than:

    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/js/highcharts.js"></script>

but I'd like to get the border displayed correctly using the latter implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a styled mode className of the series is not applied to the tooltip. You need to style it separately by using classes like `.highcharts-tooltip or highcharts-color-{n}`.

example: https://jsfiddle.net/xo05ov2f/

There is an open ticket on Highchats github regarding that behaviour - https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6448

Comment: Thanks. I agree with the initial poster on github. Not including the class name within the tooltip seems to negate the whole purpose of having a class name within the series. In short, I may as well have styled the series using highcharts-color-{n}.

Answer (score 0):

You can format the tooltip content by 'formatter' function.

```
 Highcharts.chart('container', {
    tooltip: {
      borderColor: '#FFFFFF',
      backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
      borderWidth: 0,           
      useHTML: true,
      formatter: function(){
          var content = '';
          content += '<span style="color:red;padding-right:10px;">' + 
                     '<span style="padding-right: 5px;color:' +                                                            
                      this.series.color + '">'+ '\u25CF</span>' +
                      this.series.name + ':  ' +   
                     '<span style="color:red;">' +  this.y  + '</b>' + '</span>';
                   return content;
               }
        }, 
    series: [{
             className: "graph-red",
             data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031]
         }]
   });
```

Hope it helps !!

Answer (score 0):

You're correct in thinking that `className` isn't applied to the tooltip, as at April 2019 at least.

There is a way of styling points though, using the `pointFormat` property of tooltips and `series.options.className`. Try:

`tooltip : {
    pointFormat: '<span class="{series.options.className}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: {point.y}<br/>'
}`

That adds the `className` to the point - meaning in styled mode it will be the same colour as other things given that class.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/philipnye/qrj4p1hn/4

As far as I can tell, it's not possible to use the same technique to set the tooltip border colour. So you might just want to set the tooltip border to be the same colour as the tooltip's background colour. E.g. (assuming the background colour is the default one):

`.highcharts-tooltip {
    stroke: #f7f7f7;
}`

h/t @morganfree for linking to the [open GitHub ticket about this](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6448), where one of the Highcharts team suggests this way of using `pointFormat`.